# Real-time Developer Notifications Not Sending IAP Subscription Event Messages

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

After setting up Android real-time developer notifications (RTDN) as a way to receive IAP subscription state changes to my web server, I only actually receive a certain push from Google's RTDN webhook that never includes the subscription details.  Below is the payload structure that gets delivered to my server every time a purchase subscription event happens from my app:

```
"message": {
    "data": "longstringofcharacters",
    "messageId": "604411111111111",
    "message_Id": "60442222222222",
    "publishTime": "2019-07-03T11:03:34.076Z",
    "publish_time": "2019-07-03T11:03:34.076Z",
},
"subscription": "projects/api-keyname/subscriptions/my-project-name"
```

According to Google's RTDN setup guide (https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/realtime_developer_notifications.html), the below format is what I should expect to receive anytime a new subscription is purchased, cancelled, restored, or undergoes any other related state change from a user in my app:

```
{
  "version": string,
  "packageName": string
  "eventTimeMillis": long
  "subscriptionNotification": SubscriptionNotification
  "testNotification": TestNotification
}
```

I have gone through Google's RTDN setup guide a number of times, and made sure my topic has granted publisher permissions for "Pub/Sub Publisher" using "google-play-developer-notifications@system.gserviceaccount.com" which Google says is a necessary step; doing this I believe is the reason why I'm able to receive webhook transmissions, but for some reason I don't understand why subscriptions events aren't getting transmitted.

Ultimately, my goal is to receive the correct payload which contains IAP state change details so that automatically syncs with my user database on my server.

Has anyone experienced this with RTDN when attempting to receive IAP push notifications?

Comment: I have also done the necessary configurations for setting up RTDN, by using pub/sub api and granting needed permissions. But I dont know where I will get those real time notifications. How to implement that in mobile app? any help would be thankful.

Comment: @NadeemShaikh: You'll have to setup a receiving script or system on your server to listen for and intake RTDN notifications, and you can manage that at console.cloud.google.com.  Once there and logged in, choose Pub/Sub from the long list of left-hand menu items, and then go into subscriptions: that's where you can define the URL where your webhook receiving script or system will live, and which RTDN notifications will push to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured it out: I missed in Google's guide that the payload I was expecting was base64 encoded in the "data": "longstringofcharacters" portion I pasted above.  Once I realized that, I decoded one from my logs, and found the IAP subscription details I was expecting.

Comment: Yeah, I missed that too - got to the end of the guide and went now what? The docs I was following totally missed that part out! Thanks for pointing out it was only base64 encoded. I had assumed it was encrypted.

Comment: I am getting just `"subscription": "projects/api-keyname/subscriptions/my-project-name"` in the body of the request sent to my endpoint. Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: there is no user specific data in payload, on server side how to bind a transaction with a user.After decode there is no such key by which. i can identify for which user notification is received on server. Please guide